# May a woman tie tzitzit to be worn by a man?

Tags: halacha, women, tzitzis

Would tzitzit be kosher if tied by a woman?  A woman may not wear tzitzit.
Would there be a halachic problem with a woman knotting the tzitzit on a garment to be worn by a man?  What are the relevant sources?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya S. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 9):

dailyhalacha explains the context and [writes](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1050) that

> Halacha requires that the Tzitzit be affixed to the garment and its
>   knots be tied "Lishma" – meaning, with the intention that this is
>   being done for the purpose of the Mitzva of Tzitzit. Although the
>   Rambam held that this is not necessary, normative Halacha follows the
>   view that one must affix and tie the Tzitzit with this specific
>   intention in mind. The question arises as to whether we would also
>   demand that the person tying the Tzitzit is himself included in the
>   obligation of Tzitzit. Given that women, children and gentiles are not
>   included in this Mitzva, should we disqualify them from tying the
>   Tzitzit to the garment?
>
> **Maran [the author of Shulchan Aruch] rules that a woman may, indeed, tie Tzitzit, provided that she has the required intention, and we may trust her word that she had
>   this intention. [[SA OC 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.14.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]** [see there further for children and non-Jews)

[Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/a-valid-tying-of-the-tzitzis/) brings a list of

- those who permit: first and stam opinion in Admur ibid; Michaber 14/1; Tosafus Menachos 42a; Rosh Tzitzis 13
- those who rule it is invalid: second opinion in Admur; Rama 14/1; Hagahos Maimanis in name of Maharam; Rabbeinu Tam in Gittin 45b, brought in Taz 14/1, Artzos Hachaim 14/1, brought in M”B 14/4; Kesav Sofer 1; Mahrsham 8/7; Daas Torah 14; Meishiv Davar 1/47

He concludes that

> Practically, we rule like the first opinion that they are valid,
>   although it is best to initially be stringent like the latter opinion. However, in the event that a woman or child did so, the Tzitzis is deemed valid if it was done Leshma.

See [footnotes 33-37](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/a-valid-tying-of-the-tzitzis/#ftn33) for more details.

R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff, in a detailed [article](http://rabbikaganoff.com/a-womans-guide-to-tzitzis/), writes

> It is preferable that women not be the ones who insert the tzitzis
>   strings onto the garment and tie them, since women are absolved from
>   fulfilling this mitzvah (Rama, [Orach Chayim 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.14.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and commentaries)

See also [Halachipedia footnote 12](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzitzit#cite_note-12)